# Parallel requests throwing "No buffer space available"

Tags: request, buffer, space, socketexception

My application performs 2000 requests to a web service every 5 minutes. 25 threads are started, each of which has a loop that are responsible for 80 requests. However, sometimes the following exception is thrown:

**java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available**

What can be causing this? It may be a momentary drop in the network?

Thanks.

Comment: The hosting datacenter runs with Linux 2.6.

Comment: basically this errors means that you have too many connections open.  Make sure you are closing all connections as soon as you are done with them.  Beyond that, you'd have to ask the system administrators to increase the number of allowed tcp connections.

Comment: Was what I imagined it. The only problem is that I use an api that performs this role, I just send the url as a parameter and it returns the content. But anyway, I'll check the maximum connections allowed, and if necessary, implement a thread pool to control the parallelism. Thanks! PS: Sorry for my bad english, i'm brazilian. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar situation where my windows 7 client running JMeter would start producing this error. I was running out of client connection sockets, where the default is 16384.
I ran

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=40000
```

which increases the number to 40000, and fixed my problem.
[ The default here is `netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=49152 num=16384` ]